Separating blank spaces from getline vs cin >> string
Context: This was an exercise for a "course", where I was given a file with ASCII numbers and was told to decode the ASCII numbers into words. Each word was written in one line, with each ASCII letter separated by spaces.
Example:
107 97 119 97
112 105 101 115
100 111 109

In the terminal, it did return the decoded words, but my code was marked as incorrect and I was told to use file >> line instead of (getline(file, line)) in the main function by one course admin, after which another admin told me to use (getline(file, line)), which my code already does have... I've been unable to get any feedback helpful to me so I wanted to ask here instead. Is using getline inefficient for this and is file >> line ideal? How would you separate the decoded words into separate lines, when file >> line doesn't take in blank characters?
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int stringToInt(string numberSet)
{
    int position = 1;
    int number = 0;

    for (int i = numberSet.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        number = number + (numberSet[i] - 48) * position;
        position = position * 10;
    }
    return number;
}

string convertToWord(string line)
{
    string numberSet = "";
    string word = "";
    int number;

    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    {
        if (line[i] != ' ' && line[i] != '/n')
        {
            numberSet = numberSet + line[i];
        }
        else
        {
            number = stringToInt(numberSet);
            char letter = number;
            word = word + letter;

            numberSet = "";
        }
    }

    number = stringToInt(numberSet);
    char letter = number;
    word = word + letter;

    return word;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream file;
    ofstream result;
    file.open("slowa1.txt");
    result.open("wyniki2.txt");

    string line;
    bool isEmpty = true;

    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        isEmpty = false;
        cout << convertToWord(line) << endl;
        result << convertToWord(line) << endl;
    }

    if (isEmpty)
    {
        cout << "No solutions" << endl;
        result << "No solutions" << endl;
    }

    file.close();
    result.close();
    return 0;
}


I originally used (getline(file, line)) in main function, but was told that it's wrong with no further context. For the example input above my code returned
kawa
pies
dom

Is the code wrong because I didn't use file >> line instead? How can you add '/n' or endl after each word like above by using file >> line, so the output doesn't become kawapiesdom without spaces?

Neither is wrong - whoever told you that is used to doing it one way, and doesn't know about the alternatives.  Each has advantages depending on context.   Reading a whole line means subsequent code must extract the pieces needed.  The key difference is that >> ASSUMES data in the file is in the required format, and you can get surprises if it is not (particularly if reading non-string data, such as integral values).   With getline(), subsequent code can CHECK if the string is in a correct format i.e. it is better for validating the input before extracting what you need from it.

I prefer using getline since it will ready ALL characters on a line, file >> line will only get the characters until the first seperator char.  And I would solve it like this : https://onlinegdb.com/hWYV3R2R4h (note the split_string is something I had lying around for reuse, it can seperate on a set of delimiters)

I suspect that you have learned about std::stringstream recently.

@molbdnilo Yes reading the numbers from std::string_stream would work to

Imagine, for example, your program needs to collect statistics on the data read, and one of those statistics is the number of whitespace characters read from the file (even if skipped over).   Since >> simply discards whitespace, your code will have no way of counting whitespace.  Whereas, using  getline(), it has options.

I also suspect that the "disagreement" is not a disagreement, but that you should use both getline and >>.

The exact intent of your teacher is known only my your teacher.


Is the code wrong because I didn't use file >> line instead?

We can't know the marking scheme, but given that the course admins disagree, I would suggest it isn't. You've certainly noticed the problems that file >> line has over getline(file, line), and it doesn't have benefits in this case.
What may have been marked as incorrect is your stringToInt and convertToWord functions, which can be simplified by using a std::stringstream
string convertToWord(string_view letters)
{
    istringstream in{ letters };
    string word;
    int letter;

    while(in >> letter)
    {
        word.push_back(static_cast<char>(letter));
    }

    return word;
}

Another issue is that you call convertToWord twice when writing to the two output streams.
while (getline(file, line))
{
    isEmpty = false;
    string word = convertToWord(line);
    cout << word << endl;
    result << word << endl;
}


Thank you for your help! They've been hiring new people and the exercise marking in the course has turned into a bit of a mess. But generally the marking scheme is only based on whether the code outputs the right answer, code optimisation and things like that aren't taken into account. Thank you again

I would suggest constructing the std::stringstream inside the  convertToWord() function, pass in the line as a parameter instead. Also, use std::istringstream instead of std::stringstream. string convertToWord(const string& line) { istringstream in{line}; ... } string word = convertToWord(line);
